# How to include reminder in custom visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, tasks, log-a-call

I am working on a visualforce page with custom pop & other requirements. But I am not able to include the remainder time field.

Now I am able to include remainderset checkbox. But how to add the reminder time field in vf page.

For Reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Salesforce UI, it is displayed in 2 fields which is Date and Time drop-down. You will have to use **ReminderDateTime** field to be bind in your VF page. Make sure **IsReminderSet** to true.

Something like this.

```
task.IsReminderSet = true;
task.ReminderDateTime = System.now()+1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to vf. How to display those two fields in vf page like normal standard task layout.Because if I use the inputfield with ReminderDateTime I got an error like  Unsupported attribute value in <apex:inputField>

Comment: Can you provide me the screenshot of the error which you are getting?

Comment: I am able to get it. But is it  possible to get time like picklist in standard layout?\

Comment: Yes, you can use a <apex:inputField value=""> and bind it with a custom time field.